Can a high-precision, low-current voltage source "fix" drift in a lower-precision, high-current current source?
I'm trying to generate a current source which is extremely low drift but can maintain high current (3A into a few ohms), that should be similar to this expensive high-precision current source.
However, the low-drift power supply I have (a (Yokogawa GS200) can only provide 0.2A. I happen to have laying around a much less cheaper, less precise, power supply, (a Texio PW8-3AQP), which can manage 3A, but has worse drift.
To save myself from buying the expensive new power supply rated for 3A, a suggestion by a coworker was that maybe I could use the "bad" power supply to provide the bulk of the current, and the good-but-low-current one in parallel to source or sink current to get a stable overall output current. The example below (using ideal power supplies) shows the idea:


the current source (the ["bad" supply]) provides some fluctuating current, and the voltage source (the "good" supply) tops it up, to maintain a constant 10A through the 1 ohm load.


I think this should work since V1 only needs to provide a little current, well within the Yokogawa's 0.2A capacity.
Can I actually combine power supplies like this? Using the good regulation of the Yokogawa, in voltage mode, to correct for drifts in the Texio just pumping out 3A.
Supplemental:
Also, for context, I've included a brief discription of the context for why I need this precise current source:
I am working to try to build a system that needs a very precise magnetic field. The aim is to get something around 0.30000T ± 5 µT, which requires an electromagnet with around 3.00000 A ± 50 µA current.
A collaborator's lab has achieved a good-enough solution with a commercial electromagnet (similar to this model) and a high-precision current source.
In perfect world, I would simply replicate that setup with the high-precision current source, but it's 10-15k$ usd, which I don't have the budget for.
But I have a good low-noise current source (Yokogawa GS200, which costs like 2-3k usd), but it can only drive a puny 0.2A with it. Additionally, I have an ordinary power supply (Texio PW8-3AQP) that can supply 3A of power, which I have assumed to have less precision and more drift.

I think you need to write a lot more. When I see $\lt 5:\mu\text{T}$ (earth's field is 10X that) written down as casually as one might write a whim, without much else said and nothing at all about the electromagnet structure and the location of the specific area and the reasons why, it's usually time to walk away and find someone else to work with -- my experience, anyway. That you can't see the problems with this simulation of ideal current sources and ideal voltage sources? Another reason. I still may enjoy and learn from answers I see.

That’s a common problem and stable magnet supplies can be bought off the shelf. Cost is in $10k multiples, because you get what you pay for. If you want to DIY one, look at R.A.Pease’s last project. It’s far from a simple problem. Very, very far. Genera purpose lab supplies/sources are orders of magnitude away from what you need in terms of stability.

@periblepsis, lack of details about the system is because the question is about if I can combine equipment to create a current source with low drift and high current, and not about the details of how I'm using it to make the magnetic field. But I see how it would be more helpful to know some more details, so I've added some additional details. Basically, another lab that I'm working with can get a working system with a specific high-current source which I can't afford, but with the proposed idea perhaps I might be able to get something similar. I've also added a similar electromagnet used.

How does the 5 µT of maximum noise translate to current in your setup? Is it correct to assume that you want a 300.000 ± 0.005 mT field, which translates (more or less) in 3.00000 A ± 50 µA current?

@VladimirCravero, yes, I will confirm the exact numbers there in some time (I'd have to ask this other lab), but yes this is exactly my own ballpark estimate. I'll edit the post to make it more clear that's what I'm implying.

Is there any reason why you cannot just use a big old low pass filter to achieve the noise that you want? Why would you think you need the low noise current source in parallel to the other source? I am utterly confused as your plan does not make any sense in my head. The currents are going to get summed and you will just get more noise, not less.

The two power supply idea does not work in real life - if it "worked" in the simulation then it's because the supplies were ideal. Your want this to work with real power supplies, right? Like everyone else said, describe your set up with more detail. You might not be pitching the best approach for what you are trying to achieve.

In general you can parallel current sources. If you can accurately measure the 3A to the required accuracy you might be able to feed back the error to the Yokowgawa source to compensate. For this to work, the FB would have to be a) based on a precision measurement of the 3A and b) fast enough that the drift is cancelled. A bench supply probably has a bunch of noise as well as drift so that could be problematic. Hmm.. I have one of those stupidly expensive current sources kicking around (highfinesse brand from Germany) .. have not even bothered to take it apart yet, lol. Claimed -120dB/rt(Hz).

Based on the extensive comments, I have edited the question significantly to be more clear. I have added a circuit diagram with the idea, and I have tried to make it clear what the intuition is for how a low-current, low-drift voltage source, could be used to compensate for drift in current of a high-current, moderate-drift current source.

This is not going to work. What you would have from your diagram is a voltage source. So the current will change with the resistance.
Even if the connections are perfect, if it's a copper coil, it will change a lot as it warms up.
You are asking for 17ppm stability and copper changes about +4000ppm/K.
That's not only not in the ballpark, it's about 500 miles away.

Yeah, I think this is a sensible answer, but I wonder if it will still be an improvement, as eventually the system should end up at some equilibrium temperature. But as you've said it would need to not fluctuate by <1% of 1K, which doesn't seem right even at equilibrium.

Your scenario and "proof" are completely unrelated.  Your scenario talks about connecting two current sources in parallel in which case the respective currents will just add up and any resulting drift is the sum of the individual drifts.
The proof of concept, however, parallels a voltage source with a current source in which case the current source just acts as a constant load (possibly of negative resistance) on the voltage source but the ideal voltage source determines the output completely (as long as it manages to maintain zero output resistance).
There isn't much that is more different in behavior from an ideal current source than an ideal voltage source.
One can think of using some sort of measuring bridge in order to control a large current with a high precision smaller one, but you'll not really end up with anything less complex than designing a high precision current source from the getgo.

I've added a diagram to make this more clear, as well the simulation of an ideal setup to achieve it. I think confusion was using the word choice of "current source" when one would be a voltage source, while the other is providing the current.

Your setup results in a low-drift voltage source, not a low-drift current source. That means that drift or any other fluctuations in the resistance you are driving will result in current changes. You can use a current source for shifting the working point of the voltage source into comfortable ranges but the regulated entity will be voltage, so any resistance changes will have an effect.  In particular, if you use the current to generate a magnetic field, regulating voltage instead of current will make the field react differently to matter introduced into the field.


maybe I could use the "bad" power supply to provide the bulk of the current, and the good-but-low-current one in parallel to source or sink current to get a stable overall output current.

You're halfway there. Using a rough high power supply, and correcting it, can work. But, you can't correct it with a constant current supply. You need to correct it with a controllable current supply, controlled by measuring the total current going to the load.
Or do you really need to measure current? If it's a stable magnetic field you're after, then maybe you need to measure the field to correct the magnet current. Stable current after all only gives you a stable MMF. The H field then depends on the stability of the magnet geometry (thermal expansion for instance) as well as current. The B field then depends on the stability of the permeability environment (somebody opening a steel filing cabinet in the next room for instance) as well as H field.
But let's assume your magnet environment is stable, and current control is sufficient. The simplest way is to pass it through a low-tempco sensing resistor to create a voltage. This is now compared with a reference voltage by a low-drift low noise error amplifier, typically based round an opamp. Finally, you connect feedback to close a stable control loop.
You will be able to get the data sheets for various resistors, amplifiers and voltage references to specify their noise and long-term stability. A colleague of mine had a mantra that 'if you can measure it, you can control it'. He was building and measuring low noise synthesisers, but the principle is the same. The important components controlling the noise and stability of the output are just those involved in the measurement, the sense resistor, opamp, voltage reference. The performance of the rest of the loop can be dominated by those.
Even if you can choose appropriate low noise / low drift components, getting the datasheet performance out of them, and out of a system of them, is no mean feat. You need to have the measurement skills of a Bob Pease, or my synthesiser colleague. One possible use of your precision current source is to study the circuit diagram and see how they do. Developing a low drift source from scratch could rapidly consume 10x the cost of buying the proper equipment in design time and slipped timescales. There is a reason companies can make money selling that very expensive kit.
You need to be explicit about your required specification, you may not need perfection in every parameter - noise at 1 kHz behaves differently to 10 Hz noise, and differently to drift in seconds or months. I notice your high quality low current source also has an optional measurement facility. If you use that to measure your magnet current, and repeatedly correct the current with a high resolution (but potentially low accuracy) programmable current source, that would bring your long term drift to that of the current monitoring stability. Can you application handle whatever noise you get from that, and the discrete steps when you change the correction?
If you did have the freedom to modify the GS200 (covers off, warranty voided!), could you change the current shunt so that it could handle the full 3A coil current? Then its current control loop would be able to correct the total current through the magnet, when paralleled with the noisy source, as long as it stayed stable with the change of gain.

Thanks for the advice. Sounds using the yokogawa to provide corrective feedback on the signal from a magnetometer, could work...but as you've said it sounds like something that will take a lot of time to get right.
